# How can I swap the Esc and the Caps Lock keys?

Tags: keyboard

I managed to remap the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key to <kbd>Escape</kbd>, but I can't find a way to remap the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>.

The reason why I want to do this is that I usually use X11 on Linux where this is available as an option.

Comment: Also potential dupes:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/283252/119271 and  https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281405/119271

Comment: I don't agree with marking my question as duplicate -- none of these questions precisely duplicate my question.

Comment: Have you tried any of the solutions?

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunately none of those solutions explains how to remap Escape to Caps Lock.